# How to upload a file to Windows through a netcat session?

Tags: windows, netcat

I have a `netcat` session and I want to upload a binary to the target Windows machine. How can I do so? Is there a native `wget` in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If by “native” you meant built-in, then no, but if you meant a port that runs without emulation like Cygwin, then yes:

- Many Unix tools have been ported to Windows as part of [*GNU utilities for Win32*](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), but it comes as a single package and hasn’t been updated in a [while](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/files/unxutils/current/).
- Even more Unix tools have been ported and updated more often as part of [*GnuWin Packages*](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), and also provides [individual tools](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) like [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

The binaries and source for both are available on SourceForge.